# Flask-SQLAlchemy how to use create_all with schema_translate_map

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

The SQLAlchemy provides the `Connection.execution_options.schema_translate_map` for change the schemas in execution time, as said in [docs](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/connections.html#schema-translating).

In the examples is shown how to use to perform queries, but want to know how to use it with create_all().

I'm using Flask-Sqlaclhemy and postgresql as database. Let's say I have this:

```
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
db = SQLAlchemy()

def create_app():
    app = Flask(...)
    ...
    db.init_app(app)
    ...
    return app

class User(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'user'
    __table_args__ = {'schema':'public'}
    company = db.Column(db.String(10))

class SomePublicModel(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'some_public'
    __table_args__ = {'schema':'public'}
    ...

class SomeModelByDynamicSchema(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'some_dynamic'
    __table_args__ = {'schema':'dynamic'}
    ...
```

The `dynamic` schema will be replace for other value according the user's company in execution time.

Assuming I already have in database the schemas `public` and `dynamic` and a I want to create a new schema with the tables, something like this:

```
def create_new():
    user = User(company='foo')
    db.session.execute("CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS %s" % user.company)
    db.session.connection().execution_options(schema_translate_map={'dynamic':user.company})

    #I would like to do something of the kind
    db.create_all()
```

I expected the tables to be created in the `foo` schema as `foo.some_dynamic`, but the SQLAlchemy still try to create in `dynamic` schema.

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you set execution options, you create copy of connection. This mean what create_all run without schema_translate_map.

```
>>> c = Base.session.connection()
>>> w = c.execution_options(schema_translate_map={'dynamic':'kek'})
>>> c._execution_options
immutabledict({})
>>> w._execution_options
immutabledict({'schema_translate_map': {'dynamic': 'kek'}})
```

Comment: I believe in SqlAlchemy 2.0, this has changed such that execution_options modifies in-place.
https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/blob/7cf836241aa72494b42b645a3ddec04b0a6e6061/lib/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py#L271-L273

Answer (score 0):

to achieve your goal, you could try another approach.

get the tables from old grammmar and adapt for new metadata.

```
metadata = MetaData(bind=engine, schema=db_schema)
for table in db.Model.metadata.tables.values():
    table.tometadata(metadata)
metadata.drop_all()
metadata.create_all()
```